# set selected row by clicking button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have table view and cell with one button.
I want when I click button in which row, the current row selected. (I mean the row button is in it).

I write below code but it select just first row:

```
@IBAction func btnShowAds(_ sender: Any) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    tblMain.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .bottom)
    tblMain.delegate?.tableView!(tblMain, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

what is solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get indexPath.row in cell.swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437550/how-can-i-get-indexpath-row-in-cell-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few possibilities here. **One of them and the easiest, would be using tags.**

To you give a complete solution, you would first need to add a tag to your button in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: yourReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    // Set your button tag to be equal to the indexPath.row:

    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

    // Add a target to your button making sure that you return the sender like so:

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And now this is how it would look like inside your `handlerButtonTapped()` method :

```
func handleButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    // Now you can easily access the sender's tag, (which is equal to the indexPath.row of the tapped button).

    // Access the selected cell's index path using the sender's tag like so :

    let selectedIndex = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)

    // And finally do whatever you need using this index :

    tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)

   // Now if you need to access the selected cell instead of just the index path, you could easily do so by using the table view's cellForRow method

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndex) as! YourCustomCell

}
```

**Another possibility, would be using closures.**

Create a subclass of UITableViewCell :

```
class CustomTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    var shouldSelectRow: ((CustomTableCell) -> Void)?

    // MARK: User Interaction

    @IBAction func handleDidTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Call your closure whenever the user taps on the button:

        shouldSelectRow?(self)
    }
}
```

Now you could set up your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // ...

        cell.shouldSelectRow = { (selectedCell) in

             // Since you now know which cell got selected by the user, you can access via its index path:

             let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell)

             // Do whatever you need using the selected cell here

             self.tableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndex, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
        }

        // ...

}
```

Note: You could also use delegates.

And it would work as well :)

Comment: You should not use tags to track index paths of buttons in a table view. It will fail if the table view allows you to insert, remove, or move any rows.

Comment: Well, the OP didn't say if he would implement cell insertion/removal so I thought I would give him a few different solutions so that he can choose the one that fits the best to his needs :).

Comment: That's fine. I'm simply pointing out a potential issue for future readers looking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you! Well that's actually very pertinent because depending on the situation it may indeed be a deal-breaker.