# Cannot access to the values in Struct in a table view cell. Read the described code in the screenshot below

Tags: tableview, swift4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEKO.png)[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lrK4.png) I am accessing the value from a structure in tableviewcell class , I wanted the value from the structure for making the api call .

Comment: You should update your question with the actual code instead of the screenshot. It will help others to reproduce the errors and can helps you find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is

> Can not subscript [Section] with index of type `(item).type`

is for this line

```
let item: Item = sectionData[item]
```

It explains that you cannot use item type value while subscripting on array.

You will need to pass some Index, i.e some `Int` value

Update your code with some proper index

```
let item: Item = sectionData[indexOfSectedRow]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am in tableviewcell class , I am just increasing and decreasing the quantity in a cart , I can not find the index

Comment: Without looking at more code, it is hard to suggest more. But you can take a var myIndexPath: IndexPath? in your custom TableViewCell and in cellForRowAt, you can set cell.myIndexPath = indexPath and can use that.

Comment: @CODE_APP You can find indexPath from Cell class as well. check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437550/how-can-i-get-indexpath-row-in-cell-swift/40437779

Comment: I am click a button in cart to increase and decrease the quantity , so on button of click I want to update the quantity so wanted the structure parameter to pass in ...